# Jenkinsfile and BASH shell code - Why some comments lines are honored and some are ignored and giving errors

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins version: **2.164.3**

I have my Jenkinsfile and in one of the stage, I'm calling the following code but it gives me an error. 
I don't see why it's giving me an error when syntax wise, it looks ok.

**Jenkinsfile code snapshot:**

```
 stages {
     stage("Checkout Dependent Code") {
         steps {
             sh  '''
                     set +x
                     echo -e "\n-- Checking out dependent code:"

                     echo -e "\n-- Cloning Common Code.\n"
                     git clone -b ${COMMON_REPO_BRANCH} ${SSH_GIT_URL}/project/common_utilities.git

                     ## Comment 1. Old repo
                     echo -e "\n-- Cloning Exporter Tool\n"
                     git clone -b ${TOOL_REPO_BRANCH} ${SSH_GIT_URL}/project/jira-exporter.git

                     ## Comment 2. New - 3 new repos. Comment the code for now.
                     #echo -e "\n-- Cloning Some Exporter Tool Repos\n"
                     #for r in core client extractor;
                     #do
                     #    echo -e "\n   -- Cloning: ${r}"
                     #    git clone -b ${TOOL_REPO_BRANCH} ${SSH_GIT_URL}/project/${r}.git
                     #    echo
                     #done

                     echo -e "\n\n`echo -en "\n-- Current Directory: "; pwd; echo; ls -l`\n\n"
                 '''
         }
     }
 }
```

The error message that I'm getting is:

```
10:38:38 -- Checking out dependent code:
10:38:38 
10:38:38 -- Cloning Common Code.
10:38:38 
10:38:38 Cloning into 'common_utilities'...
10:38:39 
10:38:39 -- Cloning Exporter Tool
10:38:39 
10:38:39 Cloning into 'jira-exporter'...
10:38:39 /jenkins_workspaces/workspace/development/project/my_jenkins_job/251@tmp/durable-f88d4c2a/script.sh: line 21: --: command not found
```

**Question**:

The first comment (`Comment 1` line) in the shell script logic, is honored by Jenkinsfile and no syntax issue there and we can see the output the following `echo` and `git` command works (I can see in my workspace, git repository has been cloned successfully).

Starting 2nd comment `Comment 2.` line onwards, the next few lines are all commented out in Shell logic but script fails for a line (which is commented out) somewhere before the last `echo` line where I'm printing `Current Directory: ..` line and this last echo line is not printed at all (as error happened before reaching this last `echo` line. If all lines before this last `echo` line were commented, then why did I get an error. Running the shell code (from a file) works fine on the machine.

Comment: I don't think the comment is the issue. Your shell script only has 20 lines, so something about the last line is causing the `--` to be treated as a command, rather than an argument to `echo`.

Comment: I think I figured it out.. Jenkinsfile when dealing with `\n` for Shell code `bash` and Jenkinsfile being in `Groovy` shit, is treating this character in a strange way i.e. it breaks this script's `\n` character literally and anything after `\n` character into a NEW line of code (during parsing step I guess). This works if a command is NOT commented out i.e. `echo "\n -- giga"` will work as it'll break it into a separate line of `echo "` then another line ` -- giga` and works fine. When it's `#echo "\n -- giga"` then, it's barfing as `echo` itself was COMMENTED out & `--` is failing (no echo)

Comment: @chepner it doesn't jhonour SHELL code purely in Jenkinsfile (Groovy) parsing the shell code. This can be tested if I add `cat -n $0` after `set +x` in the code (how it appears before Shell is executed). Great to know how this works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some digging, I found this:

**The problem is** `\n` and how it's treated in Groovy and Shell code.

In Jenkinsfile (Groovy) code, when it reads the code for the above mentioned 
 `stage` (in the post), it says, oh I got this SHELL `sh ''' .... '''` code and I'll go parse this in my own fancy Groovy world and create a dynamic temporary shell script (aka `..@tmp/durable-f88d4c2a/script.sh`).

First Groovy comes in (due to Jenkinsfile written in Groovy) and breaks all statements wrapped in `sh ''' ... '''` code into a new line  and then, Jenkins creates a dynamic .sh Shell script (to do the work).

This works if a command which was using `\n` was NOT commented out, but doesn't work if the command using `\n` was ACUTUALLY COMMENTED out.

**To investigate** the issue, I added the following line inside `sh ''' ... '''` section after `set +x` line.

I added `cat -n $0` (just after `set +x` line, to print the whole shell dynamic temp .sh script) and to see HOW Jenkinsfile Groovy logic actually parsed this visual looking `sh ''' ... '''` code in my Jenkinsfile ---> into a true Shell .sh script before executing it.

I found that, it treated/broke/parsed `sh ''' ... '''` section; for example, a line like:

`echo -e "\n-- Cloning Exporter Tool\n"` into the following code lines (in the dynamically created .sh script, created by Jenkins):

`echo -e "` on a line in that dynamic temprarory .sh script
then

`-- Cloning Exporter Tool` in another line, then

`"` in another line.

Now, the above code works fine as `"` double quotes are maintained and `--` actually has a valid `echo` command which uses this `--` characters to print on console output.

**When the line was:**

`#echo -e "\n-- Cloning Exporter Tool\n"` into the following code:

Groovy parsed it into a dynamic temp .sh file as:

`#echo -e "` on a line in that dynamic temprarory .sh script
then

`-- Cloning Exporter Tool` in another line, then

`"` in another line.

and here it barfs as expected (as per shell logic) and there's no COMMAND (wrapper like `echo` as it's commented out) for `-- ...` to work. Thus, we got `-- command not found`

```
10:38:38     19                         ## Comment 2. New - 3 new repos. Comment the code for now.
10:38:38     20                         #echo -e "
10:38:38     21 -- Cloning Some Exporter Tool Repos
10:38:38     22 "
```

Zeeesus!

**Conclusion**: You must use `\n` carefully in `sh ''' ... '''` section of Jenkinsfile, **either** for **comments** or **real code** lines otherwise, you'll see `<some character/word> command not found` error. Or, **better** call the above code lines via a script available in some version control tool (GIT) (rather than putting all those code lines in Jenkinsfile itself).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact issue, but try rewriting the script using more well-defined commands like `printf`.

```
stages {
     stage("Checkout Dependent Code") {
         steps {
             sh  '''
                 set +x
                 printf '\n-- Checking out dependent code:\n'

                 printf '\n-- Cloning Common Code.\n\n'
                 git clone -b "${COMMON_REPO_BRANCH}" ${SSH_GIT_URL}/project/common_utilities.git

                 ## Comment 1. Old repo
                 printf '\n-- Cloning Exporter Tool\n'
                 git clone -b "${TOOL_REPO_BRANCH}" "${SSH_GIT_URL}/project/jira-exporter.git"

                 ## Comment 2. New - 3 new repos. Comment the code for now.
                 #echo -e "\n-- Cloning Some Exporter Tool Repos\n"
                 #for r in core client extractor;
                 #do
                 #    echo -e "\n   -- Cloning: ${r}"
                 #    git clone -b ${TOOL_REPO_BRANCH} ${SSH_GIT_URL}/project/${r}.git
                 #    echo
                 #done

                 printf '\n\n\n-- Current Directory '
                 pwd
                 printf '\n'
                 ls -l
                 printf '\n\n'
             '''
         }
     }
 }
```